# get a backing bean property value from another bean

Tags: jsf

It is possible to access or to get a backing bean property value from another backing bean in JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can access another beans in the context by [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingAnotherManagedBean). You can also inject a bean as managed property of other bean in [`faces-config.xml`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther). If you're already on JSF2, you can even use `@ManagedProperty` annotation like follows:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{bean}") 
private Bean bean;
```

Comment: You're welcome. The normal way to express your thanks is however to upvote the answer by pressing the up arrow. If the answer *actually* answered/solved the question/problem, then mark it accepted as well by pressing the checkmark. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/faq